# Keyboard navigation on ANT-D table cells

Tags: antd

Is there a way to have keyboard support automatically for antd tables? I would like users to be able to navigate between table cells using the keyboard arrow keys

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check a more robust way of keyboard navigation handling with https://github.com/amanboss9/naviboard library. As `tab` key helps you to navigate through a pattern and lose focus once you are done with the page navigation.`shift`+`tab` helps in reverse navigation but still you have no control over the navigation according to the element overlaying on the screen.

- Include naviboard library in your `index.html` with `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/naviboard@2.0.0/dist/naviboard.min.js"></script>` or you can install it as well from`npm install naviboard`
- Use `class` navigable on the desired items and put `tabindex` to put the focus on them.
- Initialize the `naviBoard.setNavigation(parentID)` method with parentID as the id of the parent element of all navigable elements.

You can go through the demo of this by below jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/amanboss9/zv5hocxq/2/embedded/result